# Listview column sort

Tags: c++, listview, vcl

I am using C++ Builder VCL forms application and have a listView that has columns and multiple sub items. Can I please have some help in being able to let the listView to be sorted when the user clicks on any of the column headers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TListView.OnColumnClick` event to know which column was clicked.  Use the `TListView.CustomSort()` method to do the actual sorting.  If you do not pass a custom procedure in the `SortProc` parameter, the `TListView.OnCompare` event will be used instead.  Pass the column information from the `OnColumnClick` event to the `lParam` parameter of `CustomSort()` so it is passed to your custom sorting procedure/handler, which can then use that to decide how to sort the items (ie: if column 1 clicked then sort on `Caption`, if column 2 clicked then sort on `SubItems[0]`, etc).